# Loading Coma Separated Text files to MySQL: doesn't work correctly

Tags: mysql, csv, gtfs

I'm trying to load GTFS files (comma separated text files) to a MySQL database. MySQL Workbench Import Wizard doesn't work. I copied `agency.txt` file to `agency.csv` and select it with the wizard. Went through all the steps; everything was a green checkmark but It said '0 records imported' at the end. No errors, no warnings. 
I use mysql shell. 
This is my file:

```
>>head -2 agency.csv
agency_name,agency_url,agency_timezone,agency_lang,agency_phone,agency_fare_url
Chicago Transit Authority,http://transitchicago.com,America/Chicago,en,1-888-YOURCTA,http://www.transitchicago.com/travel_information/fares/default.aspx
```

This is my sql script to create a table and load the data:

```
CREATE TABLE agency (
    agency_name VARCHAR(255)  character set utf8,
    agency_id VARCHAR(255)  character set utf8,
    agency_url VARCHAR(255)  character set utf8,
    agency_timezone VARCHAR(255)  character set utf8
);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/cta/agency.csv' INTO TABLE agency
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(agency_name,@vagency_id,agency_url,agency_timezone)
SET agency_id = IF(agency_id IS NULL, agency_name, @vagency_id);
```

and this is what is loaded to the table:

```
mysql> select * from agency;
+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| agency_name               | agency_id                 | agency_url                 | agency_timezone |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| Chicago Transit Authority | Chicago Transit Authority | America/Chicago            | en              |
```

Note that Agency_url in the table is America/Chicago (timezone not a url).

I am not very experienced in sql technologies but I think it shouldn't be so hard to put data to a database. Can someone tell me 
1. Why is this happening? 
2. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the `agency_id` column in the `SET` clause before the actual value has been set.  Hence, it is `NULL` causing the second column to be assigned the value of the first column.  Change your code to this:

```
SET agency_id = IF(@vagency_id IS NULL, agency_name, @vagency_id);
                   ^^^ DON'T use agency_id here
```

Full code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/cta/agency.csv' INTO TABLE agency
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(agency_name, @vagency_id, agency_url, agency_timezone)
SET agency_id = IF(@vagency_id IS NULL, agency_name, @vagency_id);
```

Comment: Hey @Tim thanks for the answer. Your suggested query is not doing what I want though. This time agency url is in the agency_id field.

Comment: BTW, agency_id is an optional field in GTFS. I want to use the agency_id field as a foreign key between agency and route tables. That's why I'm trying to set an agency_id.

Comment: `This time agency url is in the agency_id field.` ... I don't see how this is possible.  Are you sure you posted the actual query and data?

Comment: Yes. I can't paste the select  query result here, it is too long. But yes. I'm sure i posted the correct query and correct data. Only thing I changed in my query before I posted is that I deleted the beginning of the file directory. That's it